# URI::InvalidURIError bad URI(is not URI?): using Tanker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, indextank

I am using IndexTank and the Tanker gem to implement full text search on my Rails application, but I get an error (URI::InvalidURIError bad URI(is not URI?)) when trying to use the search_tank method on my index.

This is the controller method where I get the error

```
def search
  if params[:query]
    @posts = Post.search_tank(params[:query], :page => 1, :per_page => 10)
  else
    @posts = []
  end
end
```

This is the part of my Post model where I define the index

```
if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] === "production"
    index = 'idx'
else
    index = 'test'
end

tankit index do
    indexes :title
    indexes :description
end

# define the callbacks to update or delete the index
after_save :update_tank_indexes
after_destroy :delete_tank_indexes
```

The search_tank method works when I test it in the rails console.  Other posts seem to suggest that this might be related to the routes set in config/routes.rb.  All I have set is this.

```
root :to => 'public#index'
match ':controller(/:action(/:id))(.:format)'
```

I have searched around for an answer but I am a bit stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a URI.parse exception, it means some url is incorrectly specified or generated. Are you sure you set up the config correctly? From the readme at https://github.com/kidpollo/tanker you need to do:

> **Initialization**
>
> If you’re using Rails, config/initializers/tanker.rb is a good place
>   for this:
>
> ```
> YourAppName::Application.config.index_tank_url = 'http://:xxxxxxxxx@xxxxx.api.indextank.com'
> ```
>
> If you are not using rails you can put this somewhere before you load
>   your models
>
> ```
> Tanker.configuration = {:url => 'http://:xxxxxxxxx@xxxxx.api.indextank.com' }
> ```
>
> You would probably want to have fancier configuration depending on
>   your environment. Be sure to copy and paste the correct url provided
>   by the IndexTank Dashboard

If you've already done that, please double check the urls for typos.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had followed the guide you mention beforehand and could not get it to work. I have managed to get it working now after restarting my web server (which I probably should have tried before) I thought if it worked in the rails console it should work in my app.